# How to Deploy an already existing Gitlab release without building the project again?

Tags: gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have a neat Gitlab pipeline which consists of 5 stages and >10 jobs which test, build, release and deploy the result on several environments.

Sometimes, we need to rollback one environment to an older release. With Jenkins this was easily done with extra job which only deployed the existing release from the repository without building the project again.

On Gitlab, it seems that I either have to create a new project with it's own build pipeline for deployment only, or add a `rule` to each job which says *don't run the build and test jobs but only a deploy job when the environment variable DEPLOY_OLD_RELEASE was set*.

I don't like either way because creating a project just for the build pipeline seems like a huge overhead, and modifying all the jobs is a huge effort and not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a Gitlab job passes, you can re-run it any number of times. So for example, if you have a deploy job that scp's a tar file to a remote server, ssh's in to extract, move to a specific dir, change symlinks etc. you can just rerun that specific job.

However, since it sounds like you have a pretty well-defined pipeline, it's likely that the tar file isn't built in your deploy job, but rather one like a "Package App" job. In this job, you might upload the final tar file as an artifact so that your deploy job can deploy it.

If this is the case, as long as your 'Package' job's artifacts still exist (since they expire either based on the server's default, or a time you specify in your job definition), you can simply re-run the Deploy job. If however those artifacts have expired, you'll have to rerun the Package job, then the Deploy job.

However, maybe your 'Package' job depends on some dependencies that aren't built in this job, for example running `npm ci` or `composer install` (for PHP projects). If these activities happen in other jobs in prior stages and are uploaded as artifacts that the 'Package' job uses, you may have to rerun these as well.

This may sound like it requires re-running a lot of jobs, but if you have you expire times set accurately for your purposes, it isn't bad. For example, I have my "build" jobs (those that install npm dependencies, etc) expire in 30 minutes since the "package" job will run immediately after those complete, and I never need them directly again. Conversely, I keep my 'package' job artifact(s) for 2 weeks so that I can redeploy relatively quickly without rebuilding dependencies.

From my experience with my apps, I almost never re-deploy a build older than 2 weeks since there is usually a newer build to replace it. You should adjust the expire times for each project however.

Here's a Pipeline Definition similar to the one I use for my projects as an example. This is a PHP backend project with a JS/Vue frontend, so most jobs won't apply, but will give you a good idea how to proceed.

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

Run Composer Install:
  stage: build
  image: composer:latest
  only:
    - tags
  needs: []
  before_script:
    - echo ${COMPOSER_AUTH_JSON} > auth.json
  script:
    - composer clearcache; composer self-update --2
    - php -d memory_limit=-1 /bin/composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 30 minutes

Npm Install:
  stage: build
  image: hub.comcast.net/code_common/spa_site_7.4:5
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
  needs: []
  script:
    - /usr/bin/npm ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 30 minutes

Package Application:
  stage: package
  image: ... #same situation as the Package job for int environment
  dependencies:
    - Run Composer Install
    - Npm Install
  needs: ["Npm Install", "Run Composer Install"]
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - npm run build
    - rm -rf .git* Vagrantfile vagrant_files .env.example .env.local CONTRIBUTING.md build.xml
    - mkdir -p bootstrap/cache
    - chmod -R go+r ./*
    - find ./ -type d -exec chmod ugo+x {} \;
    - php artisan package:discover
    - php artisan optimize
    - tar -C ../ --exclude "$CI_PIPELINE_ID.tar.gz" -zcpf $CI_PIPELINE_ID.tar.gz --warning=no-file-changed $(basename $CI_PROJECT_DIR) || [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $CI_PIPELINE_ID.tar.gz
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 30 days

Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: my_image
  needs: ["Package Application"]
  dependencies: ["Package Application"]
  script:
    - ./deploy_placeholder.sh
```

The first three jobs run build steps for multiple environments. Next I take the artifacts uploaded in the previous jobs, run things like `npm run build`, and ultimately create the .tar.gz file which is uploaded as an artifact. Finally, the Deploy job pulls down the .tar.gz file and deploys.

With this hierarchy, depending on how much time has passed between initial deployment and the redeploy, you'll only need to rerun a few jobs, which you can do with a single button press for each job.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, which helped me a lot. I just didn't know how to use `expire_in` properly together with re-running jobs.
Now I simply store the version of the release in an artifact file `version` and keep it for `4 weeks`. My deploy job only requires the `version` artifact to deploy the proper version and can be triggered up to 4 weeks after the build!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!